# How to exclude classes when compiling SWC from Haxe?

Tags: class, default, haxe, swc

This question is specifically for creating SWCs from Haxe in FlashDevelop (not from AS3 code).

Is there a compiler argument to specify some classes to NOT be compiled within a SWC? And if so, is it possible to get rid of "Main", "Lib", etc. (the most common classes embedded in the SWC by default) while compiling everything else?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For Nape I compile the swcs like:

```
haxe --macro "include('nape')" --macro "include('zpp_nape')" ...
```

with no `-main` flag, this builds a .swc that includes only the classes from the `nape` and `zpp_nape` packages.

This will still include the haxe std library, but no-one has complained so far.

Comment: Thank you very much. I'll look into the documentation, I'm guessing the "include(...)" part can accept a package name as well? That would probably be the quickest way to only compile the required classes.